# HsqlDB 1.8 Date Functions

Tags: sql, function, hsqldb

I am using HsqlDB 1.8 and cannot upgrade to 2.0 for some reasons. Now I need to insert a record including a `TimeStamp` field, but I cannot find any functions to convert a string to  `TimeStamp`
Perhaps it is easy with [HsqlDB 2.0](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N13B05), but how can I do with 1.8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CAST (string_value AS TIMESTAMP)

For example:

```
CAST ('2012-09-20 21:30:15.786' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But how can I given milliseconds such as '2012-09-20 21:30:15:786'?

Comment: Edited the answer for millisecons.